# Как правильно сформулировать равенство O(2n) = O(n)

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Существует алгоритм, который решает задачу за 2n шагов, где 2n -- размер массива входных данных. Мне нужно в конце доказательства написать, что алгоритм имеет сложность O(n). Как правильно это сформулировать в виде предложения? Просто написать:

1. "Так как алгоритм решает задачу за 2n шагов, поэтому сложность алгоритма O(n)" или
2. "Так как алгоритм решает задачу за 2n шагов, поэтому сложность алгоритма O(2n) = O(n)" или
3. "Так как алгоритм решает задачу за 2n шагов, поэтому сложность алгоритма 2n = O(n)".

Или что-то другое?

Comment: Если вы **доказываете**, то должны искать предел 2n/n и доказывать, что это - константа :)

Comment: `асимптотическая сложность алгоритма O(n)`

Comment: @Harry мне не нужно (пере)доказывать равенство O(2n) = O(n), так как это хорошо известно. Мне нужно просто прописать словами формулировку того, почему из 2n шагов алгоритма следует его сложность O(n).

Comment: Именно потому, что предел отношения равен 2...

Comment: Ни один из трёх вариантов. `O(n)` и `O(2n)` - это два множества функций. Вам нужно доказать (убедить) что они равны. Слово `алгоритм` в этом доказательстве лишнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второе. Третье некорректно, первое корректно, но один шаг опускает, второе полнее - для учебного задания лучше подходит.

Однако в комментариях речь зашла о статье. Там - первый вариант.

Только стиль поправьте. Или уберите "так как", или "поэтому", или замените "поэтому" на "то"

Comment: @МВо а как (каким словом, словами) лучше в статье писать про некоторую сложность алгоритма. Например, просто "сложность алгоритма O(n)". Или "временная сложность алгоритма O(n)", или "вычислительная сложность алгоритма O(n)"?

Comment: Можно оба варианта. В принципе вычислительная сложность включает в себя и временную и пространственную сложность, но без уточнений подразумевается в первую очередь временная.

Comment: O(2n) - мягко говоря, странное утверждение :)

Comment: @Harry В учебных выводах так пишут, после этого сразу, что это равно O(n)

Comment: Кстати, раз речь идёт о статье, а не об учебном задании то первый вариант без вариантов.